# Block s3 public url access for my image and only show the image in mobile app or website

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-s3

I have upload all my images in s3 bucket and allowing it to show in my website using s3 url, but when I access the s3 url directly in browser it showing the image, I want to block those access

Can anyone help me on how to Block s3 public url access for my image and only show the image in mobile app or website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All objects in Amazon S3 are private by default.

Access to objects can be granted in several ways:

- A **Bucket Policy** can make a whole bucket (or a part of a bucket) public to everyone. It is also possible to specify restrictions, such as IP address and referer.
- An **Access Control List** on an object can make the object public (for everyone)
- An **IAM Policy** can grant access to objects for specific **IAM Users**
- A **pre-signed URL** can provide temporary access to a private object

Based upon your question, I would recommend:

- Keep the objects private (remove Bucket Policies and ACLs)
- When a user wishes to access an image or other object, your application determines whether the user is permitted to access the object (this logic is totally up to you to write in your application)
- If they are permitted, your application can create a **pre-signed URL** in a few lines of code, which will allow the mobile app or website to access the object **for a limited time period** that your app specifies (eg 5 minutes). After this time period, the URL will no longer provide access.

Thus, your application has full control over whether somebody is permitted to access the image, while still serving the content directly from Amazon S3 (eg in a web page via a `<img>` tag).

See: [Share an Object with Others - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: Thank you so much John, really helpful can you please explain me about the pre-signed URL ? it will be more helpful

Comment: See: [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)